# Github LFS x Unity - Still can't push repo

Tags: unity-game-engine, github, git-lfs

I've tried to push my unity repo to my github but since the files are so large I thought to use LFS. Installed LFS, ran `git lfs install` in the terminal, add, commit and push, and I get the following errors:

```
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (18056/18056), done.
remote: warning: File Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.6.0/.Runtime/hostlin/lld is 57.95 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: warning: File Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.6.0/.Runtime/hostmac/dsymutil is 64.13 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: warning: File Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.6.0/.Runtime/libburst-llvm-11.dylib is 87.83 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: error: Trace: f9eeba7df30d8a51c6584e8ac73a6622802080d5c56fc4191126526d0b7a055c
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.6.0/.Runtime/hostmac/lld is 106.20 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File Assets/Firebase/Plugins/x86_64/FirebaseCppApp-8_0_0.so is 118.99 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
```

In my root i've got a classic .gitignore:

```
# This .gitignore file should be placed at the root of your Unity project directory
#
# Get latest from https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore
#
/[Ll]ibrary/
/[Tt]emp/
/[Oo]bj/
/[Bb]uild/
/[Bb]uilds/
/[Ll]ogs/
/[Uu]ser[Ss]ettings/

# MemoryCaptures can get excessive in size.
# They also could contain extremely sensitive data
/[Mm]emoryCaptures/

# Asset meta data should only be ignored when the corresponding asset is also ignored
!/[Aa]ssets/**/*.meta

# Uncomment this line if you wish to ignore the asset store tools plugin
# /[Aa]ssets/AssetStoreTools*

# Autogenerated Jetbrains Rider plugin
/[Aa]ssets/Plugins/Editor/JetBrains*

# Visual Studio cache directory
.vs/

# Gradle cache directory
.gradle/

# Autogenerated VS/MD/Consulo solution and project files
ExportedObj/
.consulo/
*.csproj
*.unityproj
*.sln
*.suo
*.tmp
*.user
*.userprefs
*.pidb
*.booproj
*.svd
*.pdb
*.mdb
*.opendb
*.VC.db

# Unity3D generated meta files
*.pidb.meta
*.pdb.meta
*.mdb.meta

# Unity3D generated file on crash reports
sysinfo.txt

# Builds
*.apk
*.aab
*.unitypackage

# Crashlytics generated file
crashlytics-build.properties

# Packed Addressables
/[Aa]ssets/[Aa]ddressable[Aa]ssets[Dd]ata/*/*.bin*

# Temporary auto-generated Android Assets
/[Aa]ssets/[Ss]treamingAssets/aa.meta
/[Aa]ssets/[Ss]treamingAssets/aa/*
```

and a classic .gitattributes

```
# Image formats:
*.tga filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.png filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.tif filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.jpg filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.gif filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.psd filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text

# Audio formats:
*.mp3 filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.wav filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.aiff filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text

# 3D model formats:
*.fbx filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.obj filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text

# Unity formats:
*.sbsar filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.unity filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text

# Other binary formats
*.dll filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

Am I missing something to initialise LFS ? it seems it's trying to push the repo without using LFS..
Thanks!

Comment: Why is it putting in library/packagecache your ignore doesnt seem to be working

Comment: Git LFS is not the golden fix it makes out to be.  The biggest problem is that once large files have been converted over if you are not careful you will find placeholder files on your filesystem instead of that 50 MB PNG file you needed.  This is because you either didn't do a `git lfs pull` or GUI clients like _GitKraken_ refuse to by default.  Also whilst you can `git lfs migrate` over say _"all PNG files over 50 MB"_ the resulting entry in **.gitattributes** doesn't support size filters and so subsequent PNGs are converted over irrespective of size.  You are much better off using `Perforce`

Comment: ...[Get Free Version Control Software From Perforce](https://www.perforce.com/products/helix-core/free-version-control) which supports large files from day 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing LFS only affects *new* commits. You'll have to rewrite the repo to move the old files to LFS as well:

- https://edwardthomson.com/blog/advent_day_23_removing_large_binaries_with_lfs.html

It's safest to do a fresh `git clone --mirror` for a few reasons:

> You can do a mirror clone, which will clone the remote into a bare repository locally so that you don't check out all your large files unnecessarily. It will also get all the remote branches and tags, and set up remote tracking branches so that you can safely perform a force push.

```
git clone --mirror git@github.com:ethomson/repo.git
git lfs migrate import --everything
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now --aggressive
git push --mirror --force
```

> **WARNING** This will change your history. Make sure all outstanding work is synchronized and all developers on your repo sync their repo before continuing to work.

> Get your users to reclone their repositories. I am generally loathe to encourage people to ever do this - a lot of people follow the delete and re-clone strategy when something goes wrong in their work and it's quite an anti-pattern. There are really no problems in Git that are so hairy that you need to get rid of the repository and start over; solving these problems without doing that will really level-up your Git knowledge.

> This is the exception - we've rewritten every branch and there's no simple way to update. Instead, cloning a new copy of the repository is the right way to go. (Bonus: it's now much quicker to clone the repository since you don't have all those messy binaries.)

Comment: I think without doing this via mirror you can simply LFS migrate everything and make usual commit for this .. this should simply convert all the files to pointers for all future commits without having to force push a new history which indeed is always a quite scary move ;)

Comment: It would work locally, but you may not have all remote branches locally. You want to make sure you rewrite *all* branches, not just the ones your machine is aware of. `--mirror` adds that safety.

Comment: You want to do this on the master branch and in the future everyone branches out from that one so other branches wouldn't really matter here ... Either way everyone will need to clone this project again so I think merging in the change from the master is the more obvious solution

Comment: Ed (who wrote the referenced blog) was part of the Microsoft Visual Studio Git team and maintains LibGit2. I'd follow his recommendation.

Comment: Knowing that it is a recommendation from someone at Microsoft I would even less listen that advice though :'D Seriously, yes makes sense if you really want to migrate the entire repo ... but for most of us normal users asking about a Unity project which is usually no huge company product it is a little bit overkill and migrating only current and future commits should be enough

Comment: He now works for GitHub... But... To each their own.

Comment: Well GitHub now belongs to Microsoft so the point is still the same tbh ;)

Comment: This was correct, just re-init a new fresh repo and it worked :)

Comment: You can also `migrate` without mirroring; for _specific files; for specific file sizes._  [More...](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/docs/man/git-lfs-migrate.1.ronn?utm_source=gitlfs_site&utm_medium=doc_man_migrate_link&utm_campaign=gitlfs)