# Github LFS with Unity unable to push file

Tags: unity-game-engine, github, git-lfs

I downloaded LFS for a new Unity project but it's not recognizing the "lld" file:

> File Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.6.6/.Runtime/hostmac/lld is 106.20 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB

I've followed [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70189297/github-lfs-x-unity-still-cant-push-repo) which details the same issue, but still the same. I also added ".file" to .gitattributes.

```
*.file filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: @MickyD  already gave you there more important solution .. but to answer your question ... `Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.6.6/.Runtime/hostmac/lld` doesn't really match the file extension `.file`, does it? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to add the Unity folder **Library** to source control.  **You should not do this.**  This folder is essentially a Unity Editor *cache* of expanded and/or editor-ready items originating in the **Packages** folder and is *automatically re-generated* by Unity if deleted.

As Unity says:

> Set up an ignore filter for the unversioned Library directory

Once you ignore this folder, Git will not attempt to add it to source control let alone Git LFS.

For a typical Unity project, **only the green-boxed** folders below **should be added to source control**:

[image]

### See also

- *"Using external version control systems with Unity"*, Unity Manual, Unity, https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/Manual/ExternalVersionControlSystemSupport.html, retrieved 2022-10-26
- *[Sample Git ignore file](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Unity.gitignore)*, gitignore, GitHub